# Is it ok to ask a generic question like "what commands are useful"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Here is a question that would seem to have a lot of opinions for answers. Are questions like this ok?

It's asking about what commands is ex mode are actually useful.

[Does Ex mode have any practical use?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/457/what-are-ex-commands-and-the-ex-mode-useful-for-in-modern-vim-file-editing)

Comment: Note that I have edited the title of the question being discussed since this Meta post was made.

Answer (score 18):

A *"what commands are useful"*-question is a very opinion-based question. Some might consider command 'foo' to be very useful, but the next might consider it to be stupid.
This would quickly spark a discussion. While this discussion *might* be interesting, it's not a good fit for the SE format in general. I don't see why vi.SE should be  an exception.

However, the question you link to, doesn't ask *"what commands are useful"*, as I read it, it asks *"What is Ex mode, and how is it useful?"*. This is a different sort of question that *can* be answered objectively.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant! I was a little doubtful when asking the Q myself for precisely this reason, but decided in the end it did fit the criteria of being objectively answerable.